# Spring autowire multiple lists into one list

Tags: java, spring, autowired

is there a way to autowire a list of a certain type that automatically merges multiple list beans?

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
  
  @Bean
  List<MyAbstractClass> getList1()...

  @Bean
  List<MyAbstractClass> getList2()...

}

@Component
public class MyComponent {

  @Autowired
  List<MyAbstractClass> combinedList1AndList2;

}
```

Currently spring tells me:

> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
> to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
> that should be consumed

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer, try it!

```js
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class CombineListsPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        // Define a list to hold the combined beans
        List<Object> combinedList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Retrieve and merge lists from the bean factory
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) registry;
        for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(List.class)) {
            combinedList.addAll(beanFactory.getBean(beanName, List.class));
        }

        // Create a new bean definition for the combined list
        BeanDefinition combinedListBeanDefinition =
                BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(ArrayList.class, () -> combinedList).getBeanDefinition();

        // Register the combined list bean definition
        registry.registerBeanDefinition("combinedList", combinedListBeanDefinition);
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        // No additional processing needed here
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! That looks nearly of what I had in mind. In the meantime I used a more simple approach in the configuration, comparable with what you suggested in the first place. The BeanFactoryPostProcessor obfuscate things to much...
Without testing I'd say this answer would be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Add extra `code` to your example. One approach to do this is by creating a `custom collection bean` that aggregates the `lists` you want to combine and then `autowire` that `custom collection bean` where needed.

```js
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class MyComponent {

    private final List<MyAbstractClass> combinedList;

    @Autowired
    public MyComponent(CombinedList combinedListBean) {
        this.combinedList = combinedListBean.getCombinedList();
    }

    // Use the combinedList as needed
}
```

`Autowire` the `custom collection bean` for your **component**

```js
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class CombinedList {
    private final List<MyAbstractClass> list1;
    private final List<MyAbstractClass> list2;

    public CombinedList(List<MyAbstractClass> list1, List<MyAbstractClass> list2) {
        this.list1 = list1;
        this.list2 = list2;
    }

    public List<MyAbstractClass> getCombinedList() {
        List<MyAbstractClass> combinedList = new ArrayList<>(list1);
        combinedList.addAll(list2);
        return combinedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I was looking for a more generic/automatic way as there will be more than 8 of these list beans. By autowiring them separately in another component would make sense if I'd like to reuse the combined component multiple times. But I need them only in one component. I was thinking in the direction of a BeanFactoryPostProcessor but was not sure if there is an easier way.